# `sort` file names which contain chars and numbers

Tags: bash, sorting

I have many related files, like this:

> data0.csv data1.csv data2.csv data11.csv data21.csv

when I `ls .`, they look like this:

```
data0.csv
data1.csv
data11.csv
data2.csv
data21.csv
```

but I want them in ascending order like this:

```
data0.csv
data1.csv
data2.csv
data11.csv
data21.csv
```

How to do it in `bash`?

Comment: What you're looking for is "natural sort". Google will tell you all about it. :)

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you:

```
ls -v *.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

For this particular example you could also do this:

```
$> ls . | sort -k3 -ta -n
data0.csv
data1.csv
data2.csv
data11.csv
data21.csv
```

Sorting numerically (`-n`) on the third field (`-k3`) using 'a' as the field separator (`-ta`).